# Jquery/Javascript increment-decrement global variable on onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, increment, decrement

I am building an event site where customers can checkout events tickets.  So I have event page where customer has to select number of tickets.  On next page,  I have a seat map where customer has to select seats as per number of tickets.

Now, Lets say customer selects 5 tickets on event page i.e. ticket_quantity = 5 and reaches seats map page.  What I am trying to do is, When customer click on buttons on seat map and seats_selected equals ticket_quantity, then only checkout button will be enabled else it should be disabled when condition is ticket_quantity != seats_selected or seats_selected > ticket_quantity or  seats_selected < ticket_quantity.

I have a script for this, but somehow it’s not working or partially working.  In script, totalSeats is global variable which will keep count of seatsSelected and then it will be used to check condition. **'thumbnail'** is a class which will toggle to **'thumbnail selected'** on selecting seat in seat map and vice versa.

```
<script>
    var totalSeats = 0;
    $('.thumbnail:not(.unavailable)').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected').length;
        totalSeats++;

        if ({{ticket_quantity}} == totalSeats) { 
            $("#button-checkout").prop("disabled", false);
        }

        if ({{ticket_quantity}} != totalSeats) {
            //totalSeats--; 
            $("#button-checkout").prop("disabled", true);
        }

    });
</script>
```

**Problem**:  It enables button when seats_selected = tickets_quantity.  But When I increase seats_selected and then decrease it (Eg: seats_selected=6 and then decrease it to 5 again, it is not enabling checkout button).  Problem is count of totalSeats in above script.  It is adding ‘1’ any time onClick event happens.  So on every onClick, it is adding 1 to count of totalSeats.  I tried totalSeats-- ;, but it’s not helping.  Any idea what’s wrong with the script? Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase or decrease, but you are increase and increase decrease.

```
<script>
    var totalSeats = 0;
    $('.thumbnail:not(.unavailable)').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')){
            if ({{ticket_quantity}} != totalSeats) {
                totalSeats--;
                $("#button-checkout").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        } else {
            if ({{ticket_quantity}} < totalSeats) {
                totalSeats++;
            }

            if ({{ticket_quantity}} == totalSeats) {
                $("#button-checkout").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

Every time you decrease your totalSeats was already increased, did you notice the bug now?

Comment: Yes I noticed the bug, But in your script, I am not getting count of totalSeats.  It's not going inside first if function and hence it never increases totalSeats count.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this code.  No errors in console, but somehow not working for me. "var" thing mentioned by @Jonas did trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply get

```
var totalSeats = $(".selected").length;
```

inside of the click handler.

---

Or you may need to check manualy if the class is set or removed:

```
if($(this).hasClass("selected")){
  $(this).removeClass("selected");
  totalSeats--;
}else{
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  totalSeats++;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked.  Thank you so much.  It was taking 2 seats because of legend on my html page for selected class. Up voted your answer.

Comment: just use `$(this).toggleClass('selected');`

Comment: @claudio santos why should i?

Comment: to avoid use the add and remove class.

Comment: @claudio and why should one avoid it ? :/ because it is faster maybe ?